# Pandas create new column every time function runs

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This is data.csv:

[image]

```
tickers = ['ACOR', 'ACM', 'ACLS', 'ACND', 'ACMR']
stats = ['mkt_cap', 'price', 'change']
```

This code creates a csv file for each stat in the assets directory:

```
date = str(dt.date.today())

for stat in stats:
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    df.set_index('ticker', inplace=True)
    df = df.loc[tickers, ['{}'.format(stat)]]
    date = str(dt.date.today())
    df.rename(columns = {'{}'.format(stat):date}, inplace=True)
    df.to_csv(assets/{}.csv'.format(stats))
```

Here is price.csv

```
ticker      2019/07/04
ACOR              7.42
ACM              37.33
...             ...
```

The problem is I need a new column to be created every time this function is run with the current date as the header. Data.csv gets updated everyday and I would like to add new data into mkt_cap.csv, prices.csv and change.csv with the new date as the header. The updated prices.csv would look like:

```
ticker      2019/07/04   2019/07/05
ACOR              7.42          XXX
ACM              37.33          XXX
...             ...
```

EDIT:

```
date = str(dt.date.today())

for stat in stats:
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    df.set_index('ticker', inplace=True)
    df = df.loc[tickers, ['{}'.format(stat)]]
    date = str(dt.date.today())
    df.rename(columns = {'{}'.format(stat):date}, inplace=True)
    df.to_csv(assets/{}.csv'.format(stats))

for col in stats.columns:
    stats["{}-{}".format(dt.date.today(),col)] = stats[col]

dataframes = []
for datapoint in stats.columns[-5:-1]:
    dataframes.append(stats[[datapoint, "ticker"]])

for dff in dataframes:
    dff.to_csv('assets/{}.csv'.format(dff.columns[1]))
```

Comment: Could you post an expected output ? Do you want one df with all the stats or one more column 'mkt_cap_i' for each new entry ?

Comment: Why new columns? Commonly you append new rows.

Comment: The next time I run this function I would like to have a third column in the mkt_cap, prices and changes CSV files with dt.date.today() as the header, data.csv gets updated daily.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = []
for i in range(0,10):
  list1.append(i)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["col1"] = list1
df['col2'] = df['col1']+5


import datetime as dt
def new_col(df):
  df[dt.datetime.now()] = df['col1']+ df['col2']
  return df

new_col(df)
```

This will create a new column when the function is called with the datetime the function is run. Not entirely sure what you are trying to do as far as the arithmetic of the new column but this should do the trick as far as creating the new column.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, it looks good. Though what does the range(0,10)  mean?

Comment: Oh its just to create a dummy list for my code. Basically append number 1-10 to an empty list. Since your files already have real data wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Oh I see. If you have the time, could you post this implementation with the code I posted? I'm having a tough time writing the new column to csv. I'm new to pandas.

Comment: yes id be happy too but what exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to just get historical data into csv format whenever a funtion is called?

Comment: Data.csv gets updated daily. I would like to run the function to add a new column of data into the stat CSV files and use the current date as the header for that column. Thank you for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in acor.columns: #or you could just use your stat list
  acor["{}-{}".format(dt.datetime.now(),col)] = acor[col]

dataframes = [] ##seperates into individual dataframes 
for datapoint in acor.columns[-5:-1]:
  dataframes.append(acor[[datapoint,"timestamp"]])###you probobly want to replace timestamp with "symbol" or "ticker"
  ###finally saves dataframes by date and stat 
for dff in dataframes:
  dff.to_csv("{}.csv".format(dff.columns[1]))
```

Comment: This looks promising. ACOR doesn't have columns though. See my edit. This didn't work for me. Think its close though. This is above my level.

Comment: acor is just the name of the dataframe, your original dataframe is just called df. so in the first two lines you would just replace acor with df

Comment: I've tried a few things but this doesn't work for me. Thank you for your help though.